# Intuitions behind python API design

Tags: python

Usually while writing code, I tend to make mistakes with some function as those functions signatures dont follow my intuition. Or more appropriately my intuition do not follow the design thinking behind these functions. I always wondered if python APIs have some inconsistencies.

For example, in python, we have:

```
>>> ','.join(['1','2','3'])
'1,2,3'

>>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
['1', '2', '3']
```

Many times I find myself doing:

```
['1','2','3'].join(',')
```

and some times (/ very rarely):

```
','.split('1,2,3')
```

Similarly I find this somewhat frustrating:

```
>>> sorted([1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]

>>> reversed([1,2,3])
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x000002008932A95
```

That is, one list function returns list, while other returns an iterator. To save me some time (usually in timed coding competition), I usually end up doing extra `list()`:

```
>>> list(reversed([1,2,3]))
[3, 2, 1]

>>> list(sorted([1,2,3]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

I believe there must be some API design standards or technical considerations behind these and am unaware of them. Can someone please share their understanding regarding these, so that it will become part of my intuition and I will do less mistakes. Or is it just the coding practice that will help me make less mistakes? Also, these are just couple of the things that I can recall now, which I usually make mistakes at. Can you share similar API confusions and intuitions behind them that you face (if you face them at all)?

Comment: Practice and reading documentation as and when you need is what builds the intuition.

Comment: I'd just say : pratice, practice and practice again until you just know what each method does, that's how you code. Unless you can tolerate to read the doc every minute

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the reasoning behind each one.

> ```
> ','.join(['1','2','3'])
> ```

Any *iterable* can be joined by a string. Not just lists. If you'd design it like `[...].join(',')`, each possible iterable would need to implement its own `join` method. You'd need `list.join`, `tuple.join`, `dict.join` etc. *Your own* classes would all need to implement their own `join` method.

Thus is makes more sense for `join` to be a method of `str` which accepts any arbitrary iterable.

> ```
> '1,2,3'.split(',')
> ```

Conversely, it only makes sense to split a string, so `split` is a method on `str`. You may be able to split other types as well, but *how* that works would differ per type, so it makes sense for each type to define its own `split` method as makes sense.

---

> ```
> sorted([1,2,3])
> ```

You must treat the entire list as a whole in order to sort it, all the list contents get shuffled around inside it during the sort operation. So you get a list as return value, as the operation intrinsically produces one anyway.

> ```
> reversed([1,2,3])
> ```

Conversely, you do *not* need to produce a complete reversed copy of the list in memory in order to reverse it; you can just go through it one item at a time. Often you want to *iterate* over a collection in the reverse order, not *store* a reversed collection. So to make it efficient and save memory, it returns an efficient iterator which allows you to do this, instead of forcing you to double your memory usage. If you need to store this as a reversed list, you can do it yourself with `list(reversed(...))`.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're saying that you need to understand the implementation to grok the api.. ;-)  I remember there was a lot of people who didn't like the order of the join operation when it was introduced.. it isn't intuitive, and it isn't like other languages' join. Frederik Lund, who I believe implemented it, was very adamant that it needed to be this way though.

Comment: To some degree, yes, the implementation dictates the API here. You _could_ have written it as `list.join`, but again, then you'd also need `tuple.join` etc. and also force each custom class to implement `join` if they needed it. If you *wanted* to put the API design first and have an "intuitive" `list.join`, then the consequences of that are vast; and arguably worse than doing `str.join`, which may *seem* counter intuitive at first, but makes perfect sense once you understand it.

Comment: So, if there is a unifying thread here that would build intuition, it's efficiency. `str.join` is more *efficient to implement* and build on Python's strong *iterable* notion than leaving it up to each class. `reversed` is more *memory efficient* when it returns an iterator. Of course, this means "efficiency" means something different in each case, so each case must be understood on its own terms.

Comment: Sure, but remember that `str.join` only joins iterables that yield strings, and `','.join([str(x) for x in myiterable])` isn't that much easier to implement than `[str(x) for x in myiterable].join(',')` -- but there was/is a stong dislike for a list method that was dependent on the type of the elements, and also of mixin-classes in the core that provide functionality, otherwise `class MyIterable(JoinableSequence):` would have worked - possibly even better/easier than the current situation (since there is no way to implement `__iter__` specifically for when it is called by `.join(..)`).

Comment: Having to do `[str(i) for i in ...].join(',')` would also be really inefficient. You'd have to produce a complete list before then joining that list into a string. This *triples* the memory usage. With `str.join` you can at least use generators: `','.join(map(str, ...))` or `','.join(str(i) for i in ...)`.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I'm sure small lists are much more efficient than generators ;-) Implementing join on the container/iterable would also solve the efficiency problem. ..and `.join(..)` would be much easier to use if it converted the elements to string itself (think `','.join(range(5))`). Regardless, we're stuck with the current api until at least Python 4, so it's just one of those quirks you'll need to get used to when learning a new language.

Comment: Sure, for small iterables, pretty much *anything* is efficient enough. But you need to consider the really _large_ cases too, and then it's nice that Python allows you complete control over how you want your containers iterated and how values are coerced or not coerced to strings. *Explicit is better than implicit*, so an implicit coercion to strings would not be desirable from this perspective.

Comment: Thoroughly appreciate the answer. Gives me good intuition whats going on behind the same as well. But why not call `','.join([1,2,3])` from within `[1,2,3].join(',')`. I mean we can add convenience container methods that will act as a proxy for `str.join()` and the cost of single call, while making API more consistent / intuitive. Is it not done to avoid redundancy?

Comment: *"… while making API more consistent / intuitive"* — That is pretty opinion based I think. Python favours _one way to do it_; having some proxy method would give you _two_ ways to do it and possibly just sow more confusion. There's little advantage needing to explain a proxy relationship between `list.join` and `str.join` over needing to explain iterables and using a `str` to join iterables.